# Cannot read property 'dsc' of undefined. Express NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I don't know what I am doing wrong and need some help please. I keep getting the same error. I log the doc it keeps saying undefined help please been trying to fix this for 16hours straight.

my model: discussionmodel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Discussion Schema
var DscSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 dsc: String,
 discussionID: String
});

// Discussion model
Dsc = mongoose.model('Discussion', DscSchema);
module.exports = Dsc;
```

my route: questions.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 
require('../models/discussionsmodel.js');

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) { 
var id = req.params.id;

Dsc.findById(id, function(err, doc){
    console.log("log doc " + doc);
    res.render('questions.ejs', {docs: doc});
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

My view: questions.ejs (just a part of the f

```
<h1>Q&A app</h1>
<h2>Discussion: <%= docs.dsc %></h2>
<h2>Questions</h2>
```

Comment: You don't need the `.js` in `require('../models/discussionsmodel.js');`, but that's is just aesthetic. You should set the `Dsc` somewhere, like `var Dsc = require('../models/discussionsmodel.js');` You're not getting an error in `question.js`?

Comment: You should probably check the `err` var. Is that set to anything? Also, can you connect directly to your mongoDB and confirm that your document exists?

Comment: Yes the document exists.

Comment: I did what you said Rodrigo Medeiros and the error is still the same. Here is the Discussions document http://puu.sh/hEVyy/c6f0b5a882.png

Comment: Thanks for the help I fixed it by changing the querry to findOne instead of findById